# How to change two variables value in PHP from a JavaScript onChange event

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I have a form with the following variables:

```
$amt and $f

$a1 and $f1
$a2 and $f2
$a3 and $f3
$a4 and $f4

$amt and $a are input numbers, while $f are label text

<input id="a1" name="a1" type="text" value="<?php echo $a1; ?>" onChange="????, document.e.submit();" />
(the same to a2, a3, and a4)
```

What I want to do is onChange, I need to replace $amt and $f.

$amt = $a1 (the user enters new)
$f = $f1

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084216/javascript-to-php-variable)

Comment: Perhaps, but that question doesn't have any real answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `AJAX` for this, i you need them processed on the back end. Assuming you are using pure JavaScript and not a library, you'll want to do something along these lines:

```
//for cross browser support
var XMLHttpFactories = 
[
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];

//find an xmlhttpfactory that will work
function createXMLHTTPObject() 
{
    var xmlhttp = false;
    for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
            try {
                    xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
            }
            catch (e) {
                    continue;
            }
            break;
    }
    return xmlhttp;
};

//process post variables for your AJAX request
function parsePostData(postData)
{
    var appendString = '?';
    for(key in postData)
        {
            appendString += key + '=' + postData[key] + '&';
        };
        appendStrTrim = appendString.substring(0, appendString.length-1)
    return appendStrTrim;
};

//this is where the magic happens
    function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) 
{
var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
if (!req) return;
var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
req.open(method,url,true);
if (postData){
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    if (postData.passwd){
        req.withCredentials = true;
    }
}
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
            var errorCode = 'HTTP error: ' + req.status;
            callback(errorCode);
        }

        var response = JSON.parse(req.response)
        if (response.jquery){
            console.log(req.getAllResponseHeaders());
        }
        if(response.data && response.data.modhash){
            reddit.control.setModHash(response.data.modhash )
        }
        if(response.data && response.data.children && typeof callback =='function'){
            callback(response.data.children);
        }else if(response.data && typeof callback=='function'){
            callback(response.data);
        }else if(typeof callback== 'function'){
            callback(response);
        };
}
if (req.readyState == 4) return;
var postString = parsePostData(postData);
req.send(postString);
};
```

So then, when you want to change the PHP variable, you would call `sendRequest()` like so:

```
`sendRequest('http://example.com/changeThosePHPVariables.php', function(){/*do this when done*/}, {amt: 'value', f: 'value'})
```

then you just need to reasign the variables using `changeThosePHPVariables.php`, where you'll find them as `$_POST['amt']` and `$_POST['f']`.

This all gets much easier if you're using a library like JQuery where you can just use $.ajax() to do the dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables and javascript are two different things.

PHP is server side, javascript client side(browser).

If you only want to swap the data locally (you didn't explain why you needed to swap the variables so I can only assume things), I suggest you to declare Javascript variable initialised with php variables.

What you need to known is that you use php to generate a page (containing html/css and javascript) with various variables. It generates text. So there is no link between PHP variables and generated output.

Comment: i understand that. obviously, my php script need to parse those two variables: $amt and $f!

Comment: What do you mean by parse `$amt and $f`? Sorry i don't get what you want to achieve. You used php syntax to name your variables so what i understand is that you want to swap two php variables on onChange input text event. However i dont know where come your variables from? Are they saved somewhere? Because between two php script call all variables are flushed. The only places variables can be saved between script are in cookie and php session. You can call a php script asynchronously (with POST or GET method according your needs) on the onChange event using AJAX (XHR object).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to get the new variable value from server and use javascript to do what you need.